# Check all tr elements for visibility:hidden between two same class tr elements

Tags: jquery, element, hidden

i've searched many place but i couldn't find a proper way to do it.
I have following structure for a table.

```
 <tr class="header">
      <td colspan="9">Header 1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="filter">
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="filter">
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>lorem ipsum</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="header">
      <td colspan="9">Header 2</td>
 </tr>
```

I am using a live table filter plugin (that effects td elements which has filter class ) for filtering unnecessary rows (with an input box).
As you can guess, plugin searchs every `tr.filter` elements and if no match it hides filter classed row.
But after when all `tr.filter` elements are hidden header rows are still visible.
So i want that:
Check for every `tr.header` elemets, if all `tr.filter` elements are hidden until next `tr.header` element that hide this `tr.header` element as well.
Eg: if there is no visible tr element between **Header 1** and **Header 2** rows, then **Header 1** row will be hidden as well.

I tried following for this, but no success:

```
 $('tr.header').each(function(){
      if ($(this).nextUntil("tr.header").is(":hidden")){
      //i tried if ($(this).nextUntil("tr.header").css('display') == 'none'){
           $(this).hide();
      } else {
           $(this).show()
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
$('tr.header').each(function(){
      if ($(this).nextUntil("tr.header").filter(function(){
           return $(this).is(':visible');
      }).length == 0){
           $(this).hide();
      } else {
           $(this).show()
      }
});
```